# private repo is not compatible with native modules

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native, npm

I have a private gitlab repo and i added this repo to my App's package.json.

**index.js** in my private gitlab repo

```
module.exports = function() {
    console.log("Hello World!!!!")
}
```

Now in my App's package.json i just call this gitlab repo using the deploy token.
Run "npm install" and this package is installed.

[image]

Finally import this in my App.js.
This works perfectly. RNN() is called and "Hello World" is logged in the console.

[image]

Now in my private Gitlab repo, i changed the index.js to the below code.

```
// module.exports = function() {
//    console.log("Hello World!!!!")
// }

import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

const { RNNativeToastLibrary } = NativeModules;

export default RNNativeToastLibrary;
```

In my android, i have created a new module with a method that just returns the device build model.

[image]

Now i install this gitlab repo again in my App. I run "npm install" it shows that package is installed. I run "react-native link native-toast" to link all the dependencies in android.
But now when i try to run the app i get this error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :native-toast.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :native-toast:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
```

I can see settings.gradle has the package
[image]

In build.gradle(app)
[image]

But for some reason i cannot add the package in my mainApplication.java
It throws cannot recognise symbol error

[image]

What am i doing wrong here??? 
Why isn't my package being recognised??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've created the android module yourself, the configuration is definitely wrong somewhere. Instead of debugging this - I suggest you use a module template like [builder-bob](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-builder-bob)

run

```sh
npx create-react-native-library [your-lib-name]
```

to create a completely setup native library (with a sample native bridge method!)